# Why does CDK ALB construct create an ICMP egress disallow rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

AWS CDK lib version: 2.62.2

When I let the CDK implicitly create the `SecurityGroup` as below:

```ts
this.alb = new ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'Alb', {
  loadBalancerName: "Raido",
  vpc: props.vpc, 
  internetFacing: true,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    onePerAz: true,
  },
  // securityGroup: props.securityGroup,
  idleTimeout: Duration.seconds(60),
  dropInvalidHeaderFields: false,
  desyncMitigationMode: DesyncMitigationMode.DEFENSIVE,
});
```

It creates an ICMP egress rule blocking port 86, like this:

```
    egress rule:
      Type: Custom ICMP - IPv4
      Protocol: 252
      Port: 86
      Destination: 255.255.255.255/32
      Description: Disallow all traffic
```

When I create my own `SecurityGroup` manually, it doesn't have the egress rule.

Why does the CDK create this egress rule, and should I add a similar rule of my own?
I'm reluctant to just copy/paste the rule without knowing what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this rule is added when `allowAllOutbound` option is `false`, which is the default for the `ApplicationLoadBalancer` construct.

My takeaway: no point in setting the bogus rule on your ALB.  If you want to `allowAllOutbound`, then do that; otherwise set your egress rules appropriate to your situation.

Apparenlty the `255.255.255.255/32` is intended to match no traffic because:

> No machine can ever actually have the 255.255.255.255 IP address